# One word or two?

Tags: word-choice

When someone says, "It's important to get it back *on line* as soon as possible," is *on line* one word or two?

Comment: There is a word "online".  There is also a two-word phrase "on line".  When you are transcribing speech, choose whichever one you like best.

Comment: Presumably it's just some weird tweak in their "guesstimated results" algorithm, but Google says it has "About 62,100 results" for both ["server back **online**"](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22server%20back%20online%22) AND ["server back **on line**"](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22server%20back%20on%20line%22).